# HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession, only in Chrome

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot application with following steps:

1. user log in into application
2. users push a button to pay some amount of money with card
3. user is redirecting to card processing/paying site where he must fill in card number, date and other stuff
4. after success the card site is redirecting to a back-ref to application, at /card-response
5. spring controller mapped at /card-response process further the payment results and ends the payment loop

Problem:

In Mozilla Firefox everything is OK

In Chrome browser first time seems to be OK (all steps 1-5) but after many times (can be second time, third time or more in a random way) the application shows login page (at step 4 when returning to application /card-response) as user is unauthenticated.

If I check the session cookie (JSESSIONID) in browser before and after step 4 (at Application->Cookies) and is the same, unaltered.
Moreover, after the application shows login page if I put directly the URL /card-response in the browser I can access application without login page so the application is considering me authenticated

From the spring application log:

```
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4f5a3111, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@3fdb1ce4]] (1/1)
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing POST /card-response
TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (1/13)
TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (2/13)
TRACE org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - **No HttpSession currently exists**
TRACE org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
```

In WebSecurityConfig I have

```
http
          .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/resources/free/**").permitAll()
             .antMatchers("/rest-mock/**").permitAll()
             .antMatchers("/reset-password-init").permitAll()
             .antMatchers("/reset-password/**").permitAll()
             .antMatchers("/remote-login/**").permitAll()
             .antMatchers("/check-certificate/**").permitAll()
              .anyRequest().authenticated()
              .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").successHandler(successHandler).permitAll()
             .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/logout")
             .and().logout().invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").permitAll()
              .and().csrf()
              .ignoringAntMatchers("/card-response/**","/rest-mock/**");
```

In case step 4 is ok (always with Firefox access and from time to time with Chrome access), the spring application log is:

```
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /card-response
TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (1/13)
TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (2/13)
TRACE org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=User [id=28327, user_name=xxxxxxxxxx, first_name=xxxxxxxxxx, last_name=xxxxxxxxxx, email=xxxxx@domain.ro], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=D24B7748BA6C2C59B1C4FAB3D16C6B19], Granted Authorities=[Role [id=3, name=Lawyer]]]] from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=User [id=28327, user_name=xxxxxxxxxx, first_name=xxxxxxxxxx, last_name=xxxxxxxxxx, email=xxxxx@domain.ro], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [SessionId=D24B7748BA6C2C59B1C4FAB3D16C6B19], Granted Authorities=[Role [id=3, name=Lawyer]]]]
TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (3/13)
```

So the session in this context is not null and everything is OK

The question is why spring security gets null session and logs "No HttpSession currently exists" but in Chrome browser session cookie is unaltered as at begin, at step 1.

For a success at step 4 the request header contains cookie:

```
POST /caav_interface/card-response HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 281
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Origin: null
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: JSESSIONID=7B0E48E550B98EAE6CBF2D7E2AB76B59
```

for a unsucces the request doesn't contain it:

```
POST /caav_interface/card-response HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 281
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Origin: null
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

So it seems Chrome doesn't always pass the cookie in the header.

Comment: Spring Security doesn't manage the session, so it's not really in Spring Security's hands. The error message you have means that when Spring Security asked the Servlet API for the session, none was returned. Your network traffic might be a better place to look for the issue, or possibly your Spring Session configuration, if you are using that module as well.

Comment: Hi, can you guide me what information is needed to debug this? In browser session cookie is present and unchanged so why the session is null? And why in Firefox everything is OK ?

Comment: Different things can make so that the app server can't find the session. Are the two apps on the same domain (e.g. localhost) and do they both have a JSESSIONID? Is your app behind a proxy? Are you using the SameSite attribute on your JSESSIONID cookie? Perhaps if you could share a sample of the network traffic for a successful and for a failed handshake, that would help.

Comment: No, the first application is on localhost and the card application is remote

Comment: I have edited my question with some network traffic

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! I'm curious about how the JSESSIONID cookie is stored in the browser. In the circumstance where Chrome isn't handing up the cookie, would you please also share a screenshot of Chrome's "Application" tab with the Cookies table highlighted? The columns I'm interested in are Domain, Path, Secure, and SameSite.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

JSESSIONID cookie without SameSite attribute is consider by Chrome to forbid passing it between different sites.

So the cookie has to have attribute  "SameSite=None; Secure" to pass it between sites.
The reason sometimes is working in Chrome is that Chrome passes it between the sites in the first 1 or 2 minutes.

Attribute Secure is needed because Chrome is considering insecure to pass cookies between sites without SSL/TLS context.
Take into consideration that for local tests/development you have to omit this attributes or to test on Firefox browser.

Implementation in java:
put in onAuthenticationSuccess from SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler override method

```
Collection<String> headers = response.getHeaders(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE);
        boolean firstHeader = true;
        // there can be multiple Set-Cookie attributes
        for (String header : headers) {
            if (firstHeader) {
                response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE,
                        String.format("%s; %s", header, "SameSite=None; Secure"));
                firstHeader = false;
                continue;
            }
            response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE,
                    String.format("%s; %s", header, "SameSite=None; Secure"));
        }
```

Thank you jzheaux for pointing me in the right direction!

Hope it helps, I spent many hours for this